# Balance left/right audio track

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have an audio file that is generally more loud than the other side. I would like for it to pan/balance equally on both sides, without having to do it by ear.

Is there any way of doing this? Through ffmpeg possibly?

Comment: Would also like an FFmpeg answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

[Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) has the option to normalize files, using `Effect > Normalize...`

Referring to the [manual](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/normalize.html):

> Use the Normalize effect to set the peak amplitude of a single track, make multiple tracks have the same peak amplitude and **equalize the balance of left and right channels of stereo tracks**.

Answer (score 0):

### Fixing unbalanced left/right audio channels in Audacity

In the absence of an FFmpeg answer to this I had to go ahead and do it in Audacity. The answer, at least in Audacity, wasn't normalisation as the other answer suggests, which I found to be an optional step that didn't address the problem of channel balance at all.

The following steps produced a decent enough result for my audio input, although I'm no audio expert and I'm not sure if this is the best method to accomplish this, especially since it feels a little too simplistic to me. If any actual audio experts know of a better method feel free to weigh in.

---

Open your audio file in [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/). If your stereo audio file's channels are imbalanced you'll probably see something like this:

[image: unbalanced stereo channels]

Note the complete absence of sound in the waveform for the left channel.

1. You'll first need to split the stereo channel to two separate mono channels so they can be manipulated independently. Right-click on the grey panel to the far-left of the channels and select `Split Stereo Track`.
2. Double-click the waveform of the channel with the most audio information - this will select all of that channel's audio. Right-click the selected waveform and click `Copy` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
3. Double-click the waveform that's mostly empty and paste the copied waveform into it with `Paste` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. You should now have information that's the exact same in both channels:

[image: copied audio]

4. Test your fixed audio by playing the audio back using the player controls above the channels and listening to each ear individually. If the results sound too low or too loud you can optionally choose to normalise both or one channel.

   Select your desired channel by double-clicking or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select both channels, then select `Effect > Normalize` from the menu, accepting the default options.

[image: normalised audio]

In my case I found that even though the waveforms looked identical, the left side still sounded louder than the other. I therefore decided to normalise only this louder channel.

If you're happy with the results, right-click the grey panel once more and select `Make Stereo Track` to merge the two mono channels back to stereo.

Export your final audio file with `File > Export > Export Audio` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.